# Is there any alternative to the map class in C++?

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa

I'm making a simple RSA crypter in C++ and I have all the calculation algorithms done, but I ran into the problem of getting the text input and converting it into numbers so that I can Xor the numbers and vice versa.

So, I was wondering if there is a simple alternative to the `std::map` class in C++ in which I could basically do.

```
    Text["A"] = 1;
```

If there is a better way to do this then please tell me.

Comment: What's wrong with `std::map` again?

Comment: If you want to map 'A' to 1, 'B' to 2, etc, you can do that just using the ASCII values (e.g. int num = toupper(ch) - 'A' + 1;) Or have I misunderstood the question?

Comment: Text *is* number. Because in computer _everything_ is number. The normal approach is to just use values of the bytes encoding the text.

Comment: There are various possibilities, but we have to know why std::map is inadequate for you: too slow? too memory consumption? what problem are you trying to fix?

Comment: I want to keep the program as light as possible and try to keep it in a procedural form, I'm not very keen on C++, but I figured it was the best tool for this job.

Comment: `std::map` works fine in procedural code. You use it just like you would an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not picky about the actual numeric values (ie, don't care much what value `'A'` should have as long as it has one), then you will be pleased to know that a `char` is represented in-memory as a (at least) 7-bits encoding which can perfectly be interpreted as a number.

Supposing that you have a `char c`, you can then say: `(int)c` to have it converted to an integral value. On most computers, where `char` is 8 bits, the value is either in [-128,+127] or in [0, 255] (it's an implementation detail whether `char` is signed or not). You can "force" it (there) to [0, 255] by a "violent" cast to `unsigned char`.